# ASUS ZENBOOK UX51VZ: BIOS fail after 204 update

Tags: boot, bios, asus-laptop, zenbook

I got some days ago a ZENBOOK UX51VZ, I hated Windows 8 therefor I successfully installed Windows 7 with all the drivers, everything was working fine; then I stupidly decided to update the BIOS to the 204 (2012.12.25) update, after I flashed and restarted the ultrabook everything went wrong: there is no boot options at all!
Now I'm literally stuck in the "Bios SetUp".

Note: The hard drives are intact, they are working find (I think so)

I used:

```
Windows     BIOS Flash Utility
BIOS FILE:  UX51VZAAS204.zip
```

Now I can't even recognize an external CD-drive!

Take a look at the BIOS:

[image: ASUS ZENBOOK UX51VZ: BIOS fail problem after 204 update]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: The BIOS you've flashed is for UX51VZA, not UX51VZ. I'm afraid all you can do is contact ASUS service center, good luck.

Comment: Often you can flash a new, or in this case, the correct bios within an existing bios if you have the image on a flash drive.

Comment: I have the same issue, want to update the BIOS on my ASUS UX51VZA. If you found the new version of it please post the answer.

Comment: Hi @Kostanos, in order to fix that problem I had send back the laptop to Asus, they fixed it because I couldn't find any solution at that time. Out of curiosity: how can you fix this problem by yourself?

Comment: My original problem is different, my notebook is turn off randomly about 2-3 times per week. So I wanted to update the BIOS to newest version to see if it will help, and I couldn't find the right version for my UX51VZA. Unfortunately I'm abroad now for a while, and can't send my notebook to Asus support yet. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Did you tried to boot from bootable USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my machine and it took 5 minutes to fix.

When you flashed the BIOS, it reset the defaults, which includes enabling secure boot and disabling CSM (compatibility support mode). Since you aren't using Windows 8, this is bad.

Flip those two options around and you should be good to go.